# Hilt Inject into ViewModel without constructor params

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

With the new dependency injection library `Hilt`, how to inject some classes into `ViewModel` without constructor params and `ViewModelFactory`?
Is it possible?

Like in `Fragment`, we use only `@AndroidEntryPoint` and `@Inject`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> how to inject some classes into ViewModel without constructor params and ViewModelFactory? Is it possible?

Hilt supports constructor injection of ViewModel via the `@HiltViewModel` (previously `@ViewModelInject`) annotation.

This allows for any `@AndroidEntryPoint`-annotated class to redefine their `defaultViewModelProviderFactory` to be the `HiltViewModelFactory`, which allows the creation of `@HiltViewModel`-annotated ViewModels correctly instantiated via Dagger/Hilt.

***NEW HILT VERSION***:

```
@HiltViewModel
class RegistrationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val someDependency: SomeDependency,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
    ...
}
```

***OLD HILT VERSION***:

```
class RegistrationViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val someDependency: SomeDependency,
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
    ...
}
```

---

And then

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ProfileFragment: Fragment(R.layout.profile_fragment) {
    private val viewModel by viewModels<RegistrationViewModel>() // <-- uses defaultViewModelProviderFactory
```

Comment: What is `viewModels<>()`?, cannot import it

Comment: `import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels` in `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"`

Comment: `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5`

Comment: I think the question is asking about how to inject object into the ViewModel rather than how to inject viewmodel to other android components. When I try to use @AndroidEntryPoint on a ViewModel, it gives me error saying sth like only Android Components are supported.

Comment: @Dhunju_likes_to_Learn because it's not an android entry point, it's a viewmodel, so `@HiltViewModel` should be used. Although I see my answer is outdated and I should update it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to inject dependency into a `ViewModel` class without constructor params. First we need to create a new interface annotated with `@EntryPoint` to access it.

> **An entry point is an interface with an accessor method for each
> binding type we want** (including its qualifier). Also, the interface
> must be annotated with `@InstallIn` to specify the component in which to
> install the entry point.

The best practice is adding the new entry point interface inside the class that uses it.

```
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

LiveData<List<MyEntity>> myListLiveData;

@ViewModelInject
public HomeViewModel(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
    
    myListLiveData = getMyDao(context).getAllPosts();
}

public LiveData<List<MyEntity>> getAllEntities() {

    return myListLiveData;
}





@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent.class)
@EntryPoint
interface MyDaoEntryPoint {
    MyDao myDao();
}

private MyDao getMyDao(Context appConext) {
    MyDaoEntryPoint hiltEntryPoint = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
            appConext,
            MyDaoEntryPoint.class
    );

    return hiltEntryPoint.myDao();
}

}
```

In the code above we created a method named `getMyDao` and used `EntryPointAccessors` to retrieve `MyDao` from  Application container.

> Notice that the interface is annotated with the `@EntryPoint` and it's
> installed in the `ApplicationComponent` since we want the dependency
> from an instance of the Application container.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent.class)
public class DatabaseModule {

    @Provides
    public static MyDao provideMyDao(MyDatabase db) {
        return db.MyDao();
    }

}
```

Though the code above has been tested and worked properly but it is not the recommended way to inject dependency into ViewModel by android officials; and unless we know what we're doing, the best way is to inject dependency into `ViewModel` through constructor injection.