# How can i user hilt Inject RepositoryManager for ViewModel(viewmodel creat by invoke)?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-hilt

**this is my RepositoryManager**

```
@Singleton
class RepositoryManager @Inject constructor(private val retrofit: Retrofit) {

    fun <T> obtainRetrofitService(serviceClass: Class<T>): T {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass)
    }

}
```

**ViewModel：**

```
class GankViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor() : BaseViewModel() {

    @Inject lateinit var repositoryManager: RepositoryManager

    fun getGankGirl() {
        repositoryManager.obtainRetrofitService(GankApi::class.java)
            .getGankGirls()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : BaseObserver<GirlBean>() {
                override fun success(data: GirlBean) {
                    showLoading(true)
                }
            })
    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class GankActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityGankBinding, GankViewModel>() {

    override fun init() {
        viewModel.getGankGirl()
    }

}
```

**BaseActivity:**

```
abstract class BaseActivity<VB : ViewBinding, VM : BaseViewModel> :RxFragmentActivity(),
    IBaseView {
    protected lateinit var binding: VB
    protected lateinit var viewModel: VM
    private val loading: BasePopupView by lazy {
        XPopup.Builder(this).asCustom(LoadingSimplePopup(this))
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val type = javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType
        val modelProvider = ViewModelProvider(this)

        val clazz0 = type.actualTypeArguments[0] as Class<VB>
        val method = clazz0.getMethod("inflate", LayoutInflater::class.java)
        binding = method.invoke(null, layoutInflater) as VB
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val clazz1 = type.actualTypeArguments[1] as Class<VM>
        viewModel = modelProvider.get(clazz1)

        init()

        viewModel.loadingEvent.observe(this, { isShow ->
            if (isShow) showLoading() else dismissLoading()
        })
    }

    abstract fun init()

    override fun showLoading() {
        if (!loading.isShow) {
            loading.show()
        }
    }

    override fun dismissLoading() {
        if (loading.isShow) {
            loading.dismiss()
        }
    }

}
```

and the EXCEPTION ：

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.kotlin, PID: 20050
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kotlin/com.cmy.domain.ui.gank.ui.GankActivity}:
> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property
> repositoryManager has not been initialized
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3897)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4076)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
> Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property repositoryManager has not been initialized
> at com.cmy.domain.ui.gank.vm.GankViewModel.getGankGirl(GankViewModel.kt:19)
> at com.cmy.domain.ui.gank.ui.GankActivity.init(GankActivity.kt:32)
> at com.cmy.common.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:38)
> at com.cmy.domain.ui.gank.ui.Hilt_GankActivity.onCreate(Hilt_GankActivity.java:30)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8085)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8073)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1320)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3870)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4076) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hilt Inject into ViewModel without constructor params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62980426/hilt-inject-into-viewmodel-without-constructor-params)

Answer (score 0):

you only need to fix your ViewModel

```
class GankViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(var repositoryManager: RepositoryManager) : BaseViewModel() {
... }
```

If you can check it again

Comment: thanks for answer,i try fix my viewmodel,and now it has anather exception

`

Cannot create an instance of class com.cmy.domain.ui.gank.vm.GankViewModel
......
 at com.cmy.common.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:36)
        at com.cmy.domain.ui.gank.ui.Hilt_GankActivity.onCreate(Hilt_GankActivity.java:30)`

Comment: You can try get viewmodel by extension

// Get a reference to the ViewModel scoped to this GrankActivity
val viewModel by viewModels<GankViewModel>()